# dropdown list sends null value to post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

this is my Get actionresult :

```
public ActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewData["categoryList"]= _categoryRepository.GetAllCategory().
            ToSelectList(c => c.Id, c => c.Name);

            return View("Add");
        }
```

this my razor that render the categoryList , and I have no trouble with that !

```
<div>
        @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Category)
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewData["categoryList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.Category)
    </div>
```

finally after submitting the page , category select send via null value to post this action

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(BlogPost blogPost)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                blogPost.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;

                _blogPostRepository.AddPost(blogPost);

                _blogPostRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Add");
            }
            return new HttpNotFoundResult("An Error Accoured while requesting your               order!");
        }
```

could anybody tell me why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(_categoryRepository.GetAllCategory(), "Id", "Name");

    // you dont need the specify View name 
    // like this: return View("Add")
    // you need to pass your model.
    return View(new BlogPost());
}
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ViewBag.CategoryList as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })
```

controller post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(BlogPost blogPost)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        blogPost.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;

        _blogPostRepository.AddPost(blogPost);

        _blogPostRepository.Save();

        // if you want to return "Add" page you should
        // initialize your viewbag and create model instance again
        ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(_categoryRepository.GetAllCategory(), "Id", "Name");
        return View(new BlogPost());
    }
    return new HttpNotFoundResult("An Error Accoured while requesting your               order!");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , But I don't have any trouble with sending the category list to view ,main problem is where the selected category dose Not sent to the Post action...

Comment: Because you dont bind it to model. pass it to view is not enough, you should bing it to model. If you dont want to use my suggestion, you should add an additional property to your postAction like this:  `public ActionResult Add(BlogPost blogPost, string Category)`

Comment: there is relationship about your BlogSpot and category list, so my suggestion is the better way for StroglyTyped logic.

Comment: If you want to bind categories to your blogPost model you should use strogly-typed helpers as dropDownListFor, not dropdownList.

Comment: but how ?? how can I make a  strongly type binding !? help me about that , do you know any sample that I could see to learn ??

Comment: check [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) , Also if you show models with relations, I will write specific example for you.